# Оценка кода с точки зрения ООП

Tags: python, ооп, инспекция-кода

Для практики начальных знаний по ООП, решил написать для тренировки небольшую модель управления ТВ с двумя видами канального плана - глобальным(для всех будущих экземпляров) и локальным(личные каналы у каждого экземпляра). Так как критично отношусь к процессу обучения и стараюсь корректировать свой код, как только вижу некрасивые моменты или костели, хотел бы дать вам мою работу для оценки и рекомендаций, правильно ли в самом коде использована стратегия с изменением канального плана, переключением канала и изменением громкости. Возможно, это можно всё было сделать гораздо лаконичнее?

```
class Televisor:
    channels=('MTV','Bridge TV','CNN','France 24') # Список общих каналов (глобальный)

    def __init__(self):
        self.__channel=1
        self.__volume=1
        self.__myChannelList=self.channels  # Инициализирую новый список каналов, который будет у каждого ТВ свой

    def sync(self):  # После добавления глобального канала, нужно сделать синхронизацию на каждом ТВ, чтобы в личном
                 # списке появился этот канал. 
        for each in self.channels:
            if each not in self.__myChannelList:
                self.__myChannelList+=(each,)
        return self.__myChannelList

    def addLocalChannel(self, newChannel): #Индивидуальные каналы для каждого ТВ
        self.__myChannelList+=(newChannel,)

    @classmethod        # Добавление общих каналов
    def addGlobalChannel(cls,newChannel):
        cls.channels+=(newChannel,)
 #------------------------------------------------- Смена текущего канала через сеттер

    @property
    def channel(self):
        return self.__channel
    @channel.setter
    def channel(self,setChannel):
        if 0<=setChannel<=len(self.__myChannelList)-1:
            self.__channel=setChannel
            print('Канал успешно изменен на', self.__myChannelList[setChannel])
        else:
            print('Такого канала нет в списке')

#---------------------------------------------------

    def volChange(self,param):
        if param=='+':
            if 0<=self.__volume<5:
                self.__volume+=1
                print('Уровень громкости {}/5'.format(self.__volume))
            else:
                print('Максимальная громкость')
        elif param=='-':
            if 0<self.__volume<=5:
                self.__volume-=1
                print('Уровень громкости {}/5'.format(self.__volume))
            else:
                print('Минимальная громкость')


tel1=Televisor()
tel1.channel=3
tel1.volChange('+')
Televisor.addGlobalChannel('NewGlobalChannel')
tel1.sync()  #без вызова этого метода новый глобальный канал не появится в кан.плане экземпляра
tel1.channel=4
tel1.addLocalChannel('NewLocalChannel')
tel1.channel=5
```

Comment: Я бы вам порекомендовал идти с такими вопросами в [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)(специальный сайт от сети Stack Exchange для оценки кода). К тому же по моему мнению, ответы на ваш вопрос будут субъективные.

Comment: Разумеется, я хотел бы просто услышать основные моменты, где совсем всё плохо и рекомендации на что, это можно изменить

Comment: Для описания того, что делают методы класса и сам класс есть специальный вид многострочных комментариев `""" ... """` в следующей строке после `class` и после `def`, используйте его, а не однострочные комментарии `#`.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что есть https://codereview.stackexchange.com